# Filter using a predicate takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, swift, regex, xcode, performance

I have 40k strings in an array. I want to filter the array so that I'll get only the matched strings. I have some preconditions like it can have a separator in between, it should be a word search and the searches can have multiple words. So, I went with the regex and it's taking a lot of time.

The following is the code that I generated just for representation purpose here.

```
var arr = [String]()
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 40000, by: 1) {
    arr.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.")
}

// We specify the words to be searched here
let searchTexts = ["aliqua", "Ut"]

// The time the execution started
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)


let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF matches[cd] %@", ".*\\b\(searchTexts.joined(separator: "[ ,.!?;:\"(')-]*"))\\b.*")
let fil = arr.filter { (str) -> Bool in
    return predicate.evaluate(with: str)
}

// The time the execution stopped
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

The time taken is 2 seconds and in an iOS simulator. It takes more in devices.

How to improve the regex? I have searched a lot of sites but it didn't help me.

**Edit:**

The above question had been modified since it involved core data.

My actual question now is how do we apply the same logic to core data fetch?

Comment: Do not use a method that requires a whole string match if all you need is a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a method that requires a whole string match if all you need is a partial match. `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` requires a full string match and you have to use `.*` or similar to ensure that. However, the `.*` greedy dot pattern grabs the whole line and then *backtracks* to accommodate text for the subsequent patterns. The more patterns there are after `.*`, the less efficient the pattern is.

You need to use a method that will allow partial matches and thus will let you get rid of `.*`, e.g. a [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range) while passing the `.regularExpression` option.

In your scenario above, you may remove `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF matches[cd] %@", ".*\\b\(searchTexts.joined(separator: "[ ,.!?;:\"(')-]*"))\\b.*"` and replace `return predicate.evaluate(with: str)` with

```
return str.range(of: "\\b\(searchTexts.joined(separator: "[ ,.!?;:\"(')-]*"))\\b", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

See the [new regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7j5duc/1) (56 steps), and [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7j5duc/2) (541 steps).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified my question now. It involves core data fetch so this solution will work partially. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Varun Still the same,  you should use a method that will allow partial regex searches.

Comment: Yes, understood. However, how can I achieve a partial match in core data fetch? As of now, if I try with the above regex, it returns me empty results.

Comment: @Varun If you mean how to do it with `NSPredicate`, then the answer is no. This kind of pattern cannot be optimized in a nice way.